# How to auto-update field on geometryChanged() signal?

Tags: pyqgis, sampling, z-value

I have a point XY layer with a Z field used only for annotations. Sometimes there is a need to update the the geometry by moving the point manually. Since the layer is stored on an mssql server, the X and Y coordinates are calculated and updated on save. As for the Z value, I created the following function that updates selected features' Z field by sampling against a raster with elevation data.

```
def dem_layer_changed(lyr: QgsRasterLayer) -> None:
"""DEM picker function.

Args:
    lyr (QgsRasterLayer): A raster layer with elevation data to sample Z value from.
"""
if QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mssql_point_layer")[0]:
    point_lyr: QgsVectorLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mssql_point_layer")[0]
    point_lyr_features: list[QgsFeature] = point_lyr.selectedFeatures()
    field_idx: int = point_lyr.fields().indexOf("Z")
    for f in point_lyr_features:
        point: QgsPointXY = f.geometry().asPoint()
        x_coord: float = point.x()
        y_coord: float = point.y()
        new_elevation_value: float = round(
            lyr.dataProvider().sample(QgsPointXY(x_coord, y_coord), 1)[0], 3
        )
        if not point_lyr.isEditable():
            if not math.isnan(new_elevation_value):
                with edit(point_lyr):
                    point_lyr.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), field_idx, new_elevation_value)
            else:
                outside_points.append(f.id())
        else:
            msg_box: QMessageBox = QMessageBox()
            msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg_box.setWindowTitle("Warning!")
            msg_box.setText("Changes in the point layer are not saved.")
            msg_box.exec_()
            dem_pick_dialog.close()
    point_lyr.removeSelection()
    point_lyr.select(
        [f.id() for f in point_lyr.getFeatures() if f.id() in outside_points]
    )
    if point_lyr.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
        msg_box: QMessageBox = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg_box.setWindowTitle("Warning!")
        msg_box.setText("Elevation has not been updated.")
        msg_box.addButton(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        new_dem_button: QAbstractButton = msg_box.button(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        new_dem_button.setText("Choose a new DEM raster")
        msg_box.addButton(QMessageBox.Ok)
        att_table_button: QAbstractButton = msg_box.button(QMessageBox.Ok)
        att_table_button.setText("Enter Z values manually")
        att_table_button.clicked.connect(att_table_show)
        msg_box.addButton(QMessageBox.Close)
        close_button: QAbstractButton = msg_box.button(QMessageBox.Close)
        close_button.setText("Close")
        msg_box.exec_()
        dem_pick_dialog.close()

dem_pick_dialog.close()
```

As can be seen from the function, I have to manually select all changed features and run a script to update the Z field. That can and has led to errors.
Is there a way to programmatically set the update Z field on `geometryChanged()` signal that the point layer emits? I tried to create an action but had no luck figuring out that solution successfully or avoiding a "button click" approach that actions, as far as I am aware, need to have. I would also like to connect the desired behavior to the mentioned layer and store it with the layer style if there is such an opportunity since the style is also stored in the mssql database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simplified example. You can of course add the `QMessageBox` functionality back in, if you wish.

```py
p = QgsProject.instance()

lyr = p.mapLayersByName('points')[0]          # change for the name of your point layer
fields = lyr.fields() 
idx = fields.indexFromName('raster value')    # change for the field you want to update

rast = p.mapLayersByName('dem')[0]            # change for the name of your raster

# function to sample the raster when a point feature's geometry changes
# the .geometryChanged signal emits the feature id and the new geometry of the feature
def update_z_value(fid, geom):
    point_xy = geom.asPoint()
    val = rast.dataProvider().sample(point_xy, 1)[0]
    lyr.changeAttributeValue(fid, idx, val)


# optional second function to sample the raster when a new feature is added
# it is slightly different to the previous function because the .featureAdded signal emits only the fid, not the geometry of the feature
def create_z_value(fid):
    feat = lyr.getFeature(fid)
    geom = feat.geometry()
    point_xy = geom.asPoint()
    val = rast.dataProvider().sample(point_xy, 1)[0]
    lyr.changeAttributeValue(fid, idx, val)
    
# connect the functions to the signals
con = lyr.geometryChanged.connect(update_z_value)
con2 = lyr.featureAdded.connect(create_z_value)

# to disconnect the signals (and halt the behaviour)
#lyr.geometryChanged.disconnect(con)
#lyr.featureAdded.disconnect(con2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! It never occurred to me to assign a variable to a signal. Do you have a suggestion to permanently attach this function to the layer?

Comment: You could use a Python Macro (I will supply the adapted code if you wish), but first consider @BenW's answer to see if it meets your requirements. It is a much simpler way of achieving (almost) the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

As much as I love using pyqgis, here is another option. You can set a default value for your Z field, and use the [raster_value](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#raster-value) function in an expression to sample the elevation from the DEM raster.

Enter the following expression as the default value for the Z field in the Attributes form tab of the Layer properties dialog:

```
round(raster_value('DEM', 1, @geometry), 3)
```

And check the 'Apply default value on update' checkbox so that the Z field will be updated whenever you move a point feature.

Note that the `@geometry` variable was introduced to [QGIS variables](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) in 3.28 so, in older versions, just replace it with `$geometry`.

Also note that if there is no layer called DEM in the project, the Z field will simply be populated/updated with a NULL value.

[image]

Being part of the layer styling, this is saved in the project file and can also be saved with the layer inside a geopackage. Not sure about an MSSQL database.

Comment: Your solution is so elegant and easy, thank you so much! I had the expression set in the attribute form for adding new features, but not in a million years would it occur to me to check the 'Apply default value on update' checkbox.

Comment: @IvanMarjanović, great. You're very welcome.